# "Must have been + present participle" usage

Tags: tenses

How can I express below idea in just one sentence?

> Someone is coming. We are not sure about it. But strong possibility is there.
>   And we assume that he is coming. But not yet reached here. We don't know the current position of his travel.

So can I say about his coming like this?

> He **must have been** coming.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to say is "He **must be** coming." If someone is coming, even presumably, and that person has not yet reached his destination, he is in the act of doing so.

"He **must have been** coming" implies that the subject was performing the action (coming), but is no longer.

Comment: Thanks. If I say ' He might be coming' what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

No. The sentence you have created expresses the past tense. "He **must have been** coming" means that you assume he was coming at some time in the past, but the action is not completed.

What you can say is "he **must be** coming" or "he **must be** on his way".  The word "must" used in this sense is not as absolute as it may seem. It simply implies that you are assuming something is true.

Comment: Thanks :) 
 
Thanks. If I say ' He might be coming' what does that mean?

Comment: If you say "he might be coming", it means you are not sure if he is coming. It expresses a possibility, but your tone of voice or facial expression will often show whether you believe "might" means "probably" or "probably not".